# How do I close a just opened window with JQuery by click?

Tags: jquery, window.open

I can now open a picture in the original size in a new pop-up window, but I want to be able to close it by clicking it. This is how I open it:

```
function bigger(service)    {       
    var image = window.open(service, 'image', 'width=510,height=470,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0,left=200,toolbar=0,top=200,resizable=0');
};
```

with this click event to activate the function:

```
$("#services div img").click(function() {
    bigger($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

This part worked perfect. But now I'm trying to close the window by clicking anywhere on the window. This is a variantion of the things I tried:

```
$(image).click(function()   {
    $(image).close();
});
```

Which gave me the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: image is not defined

Now this last bit is something I really don't know how to do, I've looked around and tried some variations but I can't seem to get it right so that's why I called in your help: How can I close this opened window by clicking it?

Comment: I think scope problems ? Please share the full code if it isn't.

Comment: there isn't more code, only unrelated coding. I basically named the new window 'image' but that left it undefined, then I saw a variation where someone defined it as a variable (var image = ...) but that didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done like this instead:

### DEMO jsFiddle

```
function bigger(service) {
    var image = window.open("", 'image', 'width=510,height=470,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0,left=200,toolbar=0,top=200,resizable=0');
    $(image.document.body).append('<img style="width:100%" src="' + service + '">').on('click', function(){
        image.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: A. Wolff I like that one very much and it's very close to working: the window can be closed by clicking it now, though the image doesnt show up this way, any chance you know why it doesn't? (I littery copy pasted your code)

Comment: @RobvandenBogaert You mean the popup doesn't show the image? If ya, any chance you replicate issue online? Aren't you using relative path?

Comment: ps. in your jsFiddle demo it works perfect but in my situatie somehow the image doesnt show up.

Comment: I will upload it so for and post the link. Sorry the error I just posted was beause I changed something to try out, forget about the error if you just read that ;)

Comment: You are using `var image = window.open("",...)` and not `var image = window.open(service,...)`, right?!

Comment: Yes I am, I've put it online:
http://test.rvdbdesign.com/index2.html (go to the 'services' page and look under 'websites' for the image to click on)

Comment: This is because you are using relative path to image, use absolute one or set `<base>` tag of window popup, just try: `bigger(this.src);` in click handler. NOTE: your image src should start with `/`

Comment: Yessss that's it! Got it working now, got some whitespace in the window but I'm sure I'll get rid of that, thank you so much! @A.Wolff

Comment: added this line to make it perfect: `.css({'padding':0+"px","margin":0+"px","overflow":"hidden"});`

Answer (score 0):

```
function bigger(service)    {       
    var image = window.open(service, 'image', 'width=510,height=470,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0,left=200,toolbar=0,top=200,resizable=0');
};
```

This limits the scope of the `image` variable to the function itself ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Fat9L/), see console for error).

So, perhaps, you need to do:

```
var image;
function bigger(service)    {       
    image = window.open(service, 'image', 'width=510,height=470,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0,left=200,toolbar=0,top=200,resizable=0');
};
```

Comment: I just thought of that indeed, it gets rid of the error but I still can't seem to activate the closing function by clicking the window
`$(image).click(function(){$(image).close();});`

Comment: @RobvandenBogaert But it works for me ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Fat9L/1/), click link).

Comment: Opening and then closing the window really doesnt seem to work here. Doesnt it have anything to do with the new window not being attached to the js file or is dat just a weird though of mine? Also, I asign the variable 'image' to the window.open event, does that actually make the variable 'image' be the window itself? I think I'm a bit confused here.